# Is an undefined equality vacuously true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, definition

[To quote Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation),

> [..] equation is an equality containing one or more variables. Solving the equation consists of determining which values of the variables make the equality true.

Consider a univariate equation $f(x) = 0$ with $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and say we want to solve the equation over $x \in A$. As I understand it, for every $x \in A$ we have a condition $f(x) = 0$ and we have to verify whether it is true. But if $\exists x \in A: x \not\in D $, then there is no condition! Does that mean that the equality is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)? I can't see why not.

But in school, if we solve something like $\frac{1}{x} = 0$, the answer is there is no solution, and, specifically, $x = 0$ is not a solution. This contradicts the above reasoning.

Comment: Don't think of it as "no condition", think of it as an impossible condition.  $x=0$ is not a solution to $1/x = 0$ for the same reason that $x=\text{mongoose}$ is not a solution, which is that plugging it in makes no sense.

Comment: Presumably in your setup $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function from some set $A$ to the real numbers (or some algebraic object where $0$ makes sense). Otherwise you need to clarify what you mean by "solve the equation over $x \in A$." So it's impossible for the quantity $f(x_0)$ to be undefined, by the definition of a function.

Comment: @Slade I don't have trouble with the $\frac{1}{0}$ expression. Why isn't $x = \text{mongoose}$ a solution with these definitions?

Comment: In particular it doesn't even make sense to ask whether $x = 0$ is a solution of $1/x = 0$ because $0$ isn't even in the domain of $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: @Minethlos $\text{mongoose}$ is presumably not in the domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ (unless you've defined the domain to be $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}) \cup \{\text{mongoose}\} \cup\cdots$ and $f(\text{mongoose}) = 0$...).

Comment: When $x\notin D$, $f(x)=0$ is vacuously false.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is $D$, the domain of $f$? If $x$ doesn't belong to the domain, then $f(x) = 0$ isn't false, it's meaningless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why?... I guess my question can be reduced to this. I also think that the answer involves choosing a better definition of equation than Wikipedia's.

Comment: @A.P.: I know but the OP insists to give it a value :)

Comment: @Minethlos Maybe you should ask why equations of the form $f(x) = 0$ are special.  After all, if any nonsensical $x$ is a solution, shouldn't it also be a solution of $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding *equations*, we have to separate *identities*, like : $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$ from equations like : $x^2+1=0$.

In the first case, we are stating :

> $\forall x \ [(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)]$,

i.e. we are saying that in e.g. the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, the formula is *true*.

This is not so for $x^2+1=0$; the formula $\forall x \ (x^2-2=0)$ is obviously *false* in $\mathbb N$.

What we are "searching for" when we ask to solve the above equation is the truth-value of the formula :

> $\exists x \ (x^2-2=0)$.

This formula is false in $\mathbb N$, while it is *true* in $\mathbb R$.

Thus, we can consider : $\exists x \in \mathbb N \ (x^2-2=0)$.

But this is **not** a case of [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#Scope_of_the_concept) statement :

> A statement is "vacuously true" if it resembles the statement $P \to Q$, where $P$ is known to be false.
>
> Statements that can be reduced to this basic form include the following universally quantified statements:
>
> > $\forall x \in A:Q(x)$, where the set $A$ is empty.

The equation we are considering : $\exists x \in \mathbb R \ (x^2-2=0)$ has not the said form, because it is not universally quantified.

Comment: Nice answer. But how do you conclude that $1/x = 0$ is false for $x=0$? How can you assign a truth value at all if $1/0$ is undefined?

Answer (score -1):

When $x\not\in D$ the formula $(\forall x)[x\in D \Rightarrow f(x)=0]$ is vacuously true.

Comment: @Minethlos I think the issue here is you're confusing the vacuously true statement $0 \in D \Rightarrow f(0)=0$ with the false statement $f(0)=0$.